# I can't start a managed server on weblogic (weblogic 10)

Tags: weblogic-10.x, appserver

I am trying to start WL managed server "MyServer", using WL Web console.
When I hit start I see a green message

```
"A request has been sent to the Node Manager to start the selected servers."
```

However, Status of Last Action says "Failed".
The log for AdminServer has one message

```
<Error> <NodeManager> <BEA-300048> <Unable to start the server MyServer : Exception while 
starting server 'MyServer': java.io.IOException: Could not rotate server output log file 
(rename from 'C:\bea10\user_projects\domains\my_domain\servers\MyServer\logs\MyServer.out' 
to 'C:\bea10\user_projects\domains\my_domain\servers\MyServer\logs\MyServer.out00305' 
failed).>
```

I suspect/recall it may have to do with the lok files, so the only edit.lok file I can find is in C:\bea10\user_projects\domains\ directory.  And it is not 0 size.  I Delete it anyway,
then go to start the MyServer again, and get the same results, with the same message.

I also, see the following in AdminServer.out log file

```
WARNING: Failed to restart: java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: The object identified by: 
'279' could not be found.  Either it was has not been exported or it has been collected 
by the distributed garbage collector.
```

It is from some time in between few times I was trying to restart MyServer, but it doesn't follow every attempt.  So, I do not know if it is related or not.

Searching the web, gives me only questions about it from people but I can't find anything helping to remedy the problem.

I can probably restart AdminServer once, if I really have to, but there are people working on it, and it is not doable on a frequent basis.

Can anyone here help?  My expertise with WL Server is a "user" - I am able to deploy apps, create servers/datasources, etc.. with the web console.  Never used command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.  For anyone interested here is what happened:
There is a tool - process explorer, from Microsoft.  It lets you enter a file name and will tell what processes own that file.
I ran it, it pointed me to one of many java.exe that owned the lock to the .out file under the weblogic.  It happened that some other instance server squired a lock to the .out file for my MyServer.  Don't know how it happened, but it did.  Once I killed that process, I was able to restart the server and redeploy the needed applications there.